# How can I include a list of doxygen ALIASES defined in an external file when compiling

Tags: doxygen, aliases

Does anyone know how I can include a list of doxygen ALIASES defined in an external file when compiling

I dont want to define ALIASES in the .doxyfile as this is for a large codebase that lots of engineers use. So to keep things simple, I want to include a file which lists all the custom ALIASES (100's) that we have defined and add/modify from time to time and get pulled in when we compile doxygen output.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm late to the party but since no one answered yet, here goes.

There is no simple way of doing this that I know of, I'm afraid, but there is one way I can think of... When you call doxygen, you do it by specifying which Doxyfile to use:

```
doxygen <file>
```

However, if you enter '-' as file name, doxygen will read/write from standard input/output instead. So you might create a simple script or program to generate your basic Doxyfile to which you can include the relevant ALIASES and output it through standard input. How you do it will depend on your OS.